# Flutter release APK does not run on Android 10 and 11

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

Flutter release APK does not run on Android 10 and 11, is there a plugin that doesn't support it?

```
name: stynext
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your build configuration to  compileSdkVersion 30 in build.gradle file